# Delete the cosmetics tag

Tags: support, tags

I made the [cosmetics](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmetics) tag assuming the creation of cosmetics would be on-topic. Since it is not, can anyone please delete the tag?

Answer (score 1):

I think homemade cosmetics are on topic.

In any cases, tags don't need to be deleted.  A tag will disappear after a certain length of time if there are no questions with that tag.